# The different of view controller and view in objective-c

Tags: objective-c

I am new to Objective-c, I want to ask what is the different between view controller and view such as "UITableView" and "UITableViewController"?

What happen if I use UITableView instead of UITableViewController?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look up the Model-View-Controller pattern in the Apple's documentation, since it is very important for using Cocoa.  Basically, the idea in Model-View-Controller is a pattern for designing your class structure.  Broadly, the model is where the application's data should be kept.  The view is what controls the application's appearance and the controller is the place where the two are assembled.  (Ideally, the view and the model classes do not even need to know about the other's existence).

Hence, the UITableView and UITableViewController are two different classes with two different purposes.  The UITableView controls the appearance of the data and the UITableViewController "controls" the view (generally by passing it the correct data for display and layout).  Since this pattern shows up again and again in Cocoa programming, you should take some time to become familiar with it.

Comment: So I can't control the data on a table view if I drop a table view instead of table view controller in Interface Builder? Thanks

Comment: You control the data by implementing the TableView DataSource.  Usually that management is doing in the view controller.  You can *use* a UITableView without a UITableViewController, you just need to implement the data source somewhere (probably on whatever view controller the table view is a part of).

Actually UITableViewController is mostly a convenience class that is useful when the whole screen is one table.  I personally almost never use it.  I just add a table view to a UIViewController subclass and implement the Data Source.

Answer (score 0):

They are two different things, they cannot be substituted for the other.

iOS follows the MVC design pattern, which stands for Model-View-Controller. The two classes you mention are 2 pieces of the overall puzzle.

The View is what gets displayed on the screen. That is its responsibility. So, the TableView is responsible for telling the phone what to render on the screen.

The View is also accompanied by the Controller. The controller decides what to do when something happens (user interaction, and other events that can happen at any time). So, the TableViewController is responsible for making the table do stuff (for example, telling the TableView what data to use for displaying on the screen).

So to sum it up, they are completely different, but they work very closely together in your application (you will almost always have 1 Controller for each View.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the short answer is that one is the View and one is the Controller. Combine this with your data (the Model) and you have all the parts of MVC (Model - View - Controller).

Think of it this way, the UITableViewController *controls* the UITableview. They are complementary and they need each other to work.